# matching filename of an image with filename in pandas dataframe to copy matched images into a dest folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Can anyone help me with this: I am facing an issue while trying to  copy the matched images based on the filename in the Pandas dataframe with the actual image filename in a folder into a destination folder. `shutil.copy` is throwing a error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20161207-112141-0.jpg?

```
for name in os.listdir('Weed-4class-37'):
    if name in df.Filename:
        shutil.move(name, destination)
```

Comment: Have you checked if the file is acutally there?

Answer (score 0):

```
 for name in src_dir: #glob.glob('Weed-4class-37/*.jpg')
         for i in range(len(df_filenames)): #df.Filename.tolist()
             if name.endswith(df_filenames[i]):
                 shutil.copy(name, destination)
```

This piece of code was working but it is comparing the  filename with all the filenames because of the nested loop and it is not an efficient one

Comment: Just add a `break` after `shutil...` to stop the inner loop after the first match?